# Detect that a joint doesn't have an connected body anymore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a dynamically generated list of `GameObjects` that are connected to eachother using `SpringJoint`, later I need to destroy some of the `GameObject`'s but the `SprintJoint` connection to the recently destroyed `GameObject` remains in the other objects, in the Unity Inspector I can see that the connected body appears as missing as expected since the object doesn't exists anymore:

[image]

But I'm trying to detect this from code so I can delete the `SprintJoint` entirely, I'm currently using this code but seems like `connectedBody` is returning a `RigidBody` even if the parent object doesn't exists anymore:

```
foreach (GameObject cell in combined)
{
    SpringJoint joint = cell.GetComponent<SpringJoint>();
    if (joint.connectedBody == null)
        Destroy(joint);
}
```

I also tried checking if the `GameObject` exists like this:

```
foreach (GameObject cell in combined)
{
    SpringJoint joint = cell.GetComponent<SpringJoint>();
    Rigidbody rg = joint.connectedBody;
    if (rg.gameObject == null)
        Destroy(joint);
}
```

What's the correct way of checking if the connected body doesn't exists anymore?

Comment: Are you sure that your code is being called? I was not able to replicate this issue. The code I used is `joint = gameObject.GetComponent<SpringJoint>(); if (joint.connectedBody is null) { Debug.LogError("Destroyed joint"); Destroy(joint); } else { Debug.Log(joint.connectedBody.name); }`

Comment: Yes, I actually debugged the code line by line and `connectedBody` always returns a `RigidBody` even if the Inspector says that it is missing

Comment: Can you post the entire script that includes this?

Comment: You will probably have a lot better luck asking this question here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `== null` check try to rather use the [`bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html)

```
foreach (var cell in combined)
{
    var joint = cell.GetComponent<SpringJoint>();
    if(!joint.connectedBody)
    {
        Destroy(joint);
    }
}
```

Note that `Destroy` does **not** immediately make your objects `null`! It is rather only marked as "dead" and the actual deletion is delayed until the GC kicks in and actually "destroyes" the object.

The `bool` operator on the other hand already marks your object as invalid as soon as `Destroy` was called.